# Object reference null when accessing ecp - Exchange 2013

Tags: outlook-web-app, exchange-server-2013

We have Exchange 2013 CU17 setup on Windows Server 2012 R2 with CAS and mailbox being on two different machines. We have developed a HTTP module for performing some tasks. Both native ECP and OWA works fine without the custom HTTP module. But when custom module is enabled, OWA works fine but ECP throws the following exception :

[image]

Custom module invokes /ecp/auth/owaauth.dll which further invokes ecp/

The same is followed for OWA. It invokes /owa/auth/owaauth.dll which further invokes owa/ and it works fine.

Basic authentication is being used.

Any information on NeedCrossSiteRedirect function of owaauth.dll should do.

Comment: We're going to need to see the full stack trace, and any relevant code from the custom module in order to help.

Comment: This is the full stack trace. Since the issue occurs in owaauth.dll which is a microsoft dll, we cannot extract more information. Also the code for custom module is elaborative and difficult to share here.